# What is the difference between a Computed Property and a Stored Value Property in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, properties

### Question:

What is the difference between the two lines in **Row.swift**?

### Context:

**Row.swift**

```
open class Row {

  // Existing code (Good):
  public var cellIdentifier: String { return String(describing self) }

  // The change (Bad):
  public var cellIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)
```

**DifferentRow.swift**

```
public class DifferentRow: Row {

  public override var cellIdentifier: String { return "\(super.cellIdentifier)" }
  // returns the error below
```

### Error:

*Cannot override mutable property with read-only property 'cellIdentifier'*

Comment: Where is this code located inside the file? Give us some context.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
public var cellIdentifier: String { return String(describing self) }
```

is defining a *computed property*.  No value is stored.  Every time you access `cellIdentifier` the closure runs and returns the `String`.  It is read-only because only the getter has been provided.

This:

```
public var cellIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)
```

is a *stored value property* and it is read/write.

The error is telling you that you can't replace a property that has read/write capabilities with one that has only read capabilities.

**Note:** if you are initializing a property with a value, you can't access `self` because `self` doesn't represent the class/struct instance until the object is completely initialized.  If you made the property a `lazy var`, you could use `self` in the initialization, because then the property would be initialized once the first time it is accessed.

You can read more about Swift properties [here in the Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html)

Comment: Also self cannot be accessed outside of a method or closure right? Can you explain that part a bit?

Answer (score 1):

You can’t override a “read from and write to”-property with a property which one can only read from.

You can assign a different value:

```
public override var cellIdentifier: String = “newValue”
```

or create both a set and a get implementation:

```
public override var cellIdentifier: String {
    get { return “\(super.cellIdentifier)” }
    set { super.cellIdentifier = newValue }
}
```

Under `Computed Properties` read more on this [syntax](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is quite confusing.

The problem with

```
public var cellIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)
```

is the reference to `self`:

- When assigning `cellIdentifier` during definition, `self` is not guarateed to be fully initialized.
- Therefore, it is forbiddin to call a function (like `String(describing:)`) and hand-in the half-initilized `self`

One solution could be to make `cellIdentifier` a lazy property:

```
public lazy var cellIdentifier: String = String(describing: self)
```

This will automatically delay the function call to the time after initialization has finished.